# How to get the PID, real user ID, priority for the current subprocess running, for his parent and for the parents parent

Tags: python, linux

Sorry this is a uni assigment and i'm lost. Have been breaking my head over it for quite some time.
Here is the text: *On the screen print the next data : PID, real user ID, priority for the current subprocess that is running, for his parent, and for the parents parent. Also check if there is the amount of processes running. If not infrom the user.*
The code so far.
The output is Partly good as far as i understand. I get the pid and ppid of the current running process. I'm just confused about the parent of parent thing. I fixed up the code and got this output that should not be separated.

```
def f1():
    while True: 
        print ('\nInput a number in range from 1 to 10: ')
        n = input()
        
        if int(n) not in range(1,11):
            print('Number is not in given range')
            continue
        else:
            pid_fork = os.fork()
            change_dir() # 
            if pid_fork == 0:
                user = os.getlogin()
                pid = os.getpid()
                print ("{:<15}\t{:<15}".format('PID','User','Priorty'))
                print("{:<15}\t{:<15}".format(pid,user))
                
            if pid_fork != 0:
                user = os.getlogin()
                pid = os.getpid()
                ppid = os.getppid()
                print ("{:<15}\t{:<15}".format('PID','User','Priorty'))
                print("{:<15}\t{:<15}".format(pid,user))
                print("{:<15}\t{:<15}".format(ppid,user))
            break
```

```
PID             Korisnik       
3481           user     
3473           user
```

```
PID             Korisnik       
3500            user
```

Sorry again for posting uni assigments but i ain't getting much help anywhere else.

Comment: Can you tell us more about where you're having problems? Is your code producing incorrect output, or are you not sure how to obtain some of the values at all?

Comment: i'll add some output because i'm not sure if i'm getting the needed data.

Comment: I'm not sure how to obtain some of the values. What is the current subprocess? How to get the parents parent data. Its really confusing to me.